# Problems in datatype while csv file as panda dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, import

I have been trying to import my dataset using read.csv in python notebook. 
However, on importing my dataset I see that the datatype of each column becomes as object. 
 [Plz click this image to see the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eayYS.png)

Is there a way that I can retain the datatypes of the columns same as that of the csv file ?

I tried using multiple other ways but it didn’t workout. It would help if anyone point us to some right function to do this. IF there is a way to control datatype of each column while importing that would be great.

Comment: Can you share the code you were using to read the csv files?

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when you have inconsistent datatypes, e.g. integers and characters such as a blank space.  It is difficult to tell without viewing a sample of your actual data, but I suspect this is the issue.  For example,

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([1, 2, '']).info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0    3 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 48.0+ bytes
```

To circumvent this issue, you need to replace these values such as "" with a sentient value such as -1 (the actual value would depend on your use case).

Comment: Thanks Alexander.  It was the case, as you mentioned it. There was an entire row of header left in the data which affected it.